# Android status bar background color set to R.attr.colorPrimary but uses wrong color

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-5.0-lollipop

Using the new Lollipop v21 API, I am trying to set the background color of a translucent Status Bar using [`setStatusBarBackgroundColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setStatusBarBackgroundColor(int)), but using `R.attr.colorPrimary` results in the wrong color (it uses a purple color instead of the light blue I specified as the colorPrimary).

**How do I properly setup my primary color so that `R.attr.colorPrimary` refers to the colorPrimary I have set in `styles.xml`?**

This is the offending code:

```
nav_drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
nav_drawer.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(R.attr.colorPrimary);
```

This is the relevant section in my `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <!-- Use Lollipop's animated hamburger-arrow as drawer indicator -->
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

    <!-- Action Mode's bar overlays the app bar instead of pushing it down-->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <!-- Status Bar is translucent -->
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

    <!-- Colors -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/lightblue</item>

</style>
```

And yes, I am actually using this AppTheme in my manifest:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [setStatusBarBackgroundColor documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setStatusBarBackgroundColor(int)):

> Parameters
>
> **color**    Color to use as a background drawable to draw behind the status bar in 0xAARRGGBB format.

But you are passing in an attribute id. You'll need to decode the attribute to get the actual color:

```
 TypedValue typedValue = new  TypedValue();
 context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValue, true); 
 final  int color = typedValue.data;
 nav_drawer.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color);
```

Comment: This definitely works (thank you) but do you know of a more convenient way to access my theme's colorPrimary?

Comment: I would have suggested it if I knew of one, but attributes are indirections that could lead to references that could lead to references that could be a value you need to call getColor() on, so there's potentially a lot the system is doing in those few lines.

Comment: It's not working for me, Logging this error: `Exception dispatching input event.
03-17 08:55:18.476 14839-14839/project..... E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
03-17 08:55:18.476 14839-14839/project..... E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:  `

Comment: `Resource ID #0x0 at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1315) at android.content.res.HwResources.getColor(HwResources.java:768) at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor(ContextCompat.java:434)
                                                                            at project.....MainLayout.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:80)
                                                                            at project.....MainLayout.RecyclerTouchListener.onInterceptTouchEvent`